# Apex authentication package

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

A little background,

As we all know, when an Oracle sample application is installed, a log in page 101 is created.  There are processes that call for a package apex_authentication and a function in that package called send_username_login_cookie.

My question,

I want to look at the code to study (I am new and learning Oracle).

I went into developer to see if I could look at the package but I can not find it.  Does anyone know where I can find "apex_authentication.send_login_username_cookie"?

I expanded all the users and used developer's "find object" feature in the "view" tab.

I have been reading the apex_authentication documentation but it does not say where the package is located. (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_authentication.htm#AEAPI29149)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're new and learning Oracle, trying to look at the internal code in APEX is probably not the place to start. Look at the code in the example applications instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APEX_AUTHENTICATION` is a synonym for the `wwv_flow_authentication_api` package.  However, you won't be able to view the package body itself as it's been wrapped (obfuscated).  That said, the `send_login_username_cookie` procedure likely is a wrapper for the `OWA_COOKIE.SEND` function.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that makes sense.